# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'advertisement' available as request attribute

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, kotlin, thymeleaf

> I bind the data properly but when I run the page and fill the
> requirement details and press send button it shows success popup
> message, when press okay button success message it redirect me to an
> blank support page but my requirement is when press okay button on
> success message it redirect me to same support page with all the
> design in that page.
> here is the error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'advertisement' available as request attribute
```

> HomeController

```
 @PostMapping("/support")
        @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
        fun contactUS(
            model: Model,
            @RequestParam(name = "full_name") full_name: String,
            @RequestParam(name = "email") email: String,
            @RequestParam(name = "comment") comment: String,
        ) {
            val map = HashMap<String, Any>()
            map["full_name"] = full_name
            map["email"] = email
            map["comment"] = comment
    
            postRequestClient(restTemplate, SUPPORT_POST, null, ContactUs::class.java, map) {
                print(it)
            }
        }
```

> ContactUs.kt

```
package com.ape.model

data class ContactUs(
    val full_name:String?="",
    val email:String?="",
    val comment:String?=""
)
```

> Support.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.thymeleaf.org ">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="ie=edge" http-equiv="x-ua-compatible">
    <meta content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" name="viewport">
    <meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable">
    <meta content="black" name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style">
    <meta content="yes" name="apple-touch-fullscreen">
    <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection">
    <meta content="" name="author">
    <meta content="" name="description">
    <meta content="" name="keywords">
    <title>APE :: Support</title>
    <!-- ================= Favicon ================== -->
    <link href="images/logo.svg" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76">
    <link href="images/logo.svg" rel="icon" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
    <link href="images/logo.svg" rel="icon" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
    <link href="images/logo.svg" rel="manifest">
    <meta content="#da532c" name="msapplication-TileColor">
    <meta content="#ffffff" name="theme-color">

    <link href="css/style.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/responsive.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

<!-- loader -->
<div class="preloader">
    <div class="loader-spin">
        <div class="diamonds">
            <div class="diamond diamond-1"></div>
            <div class="diamond diamond-2"></div>
            <div class="diamond diamond-4"></div>
            <div class="diamond diamond-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Header -->
<header class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="header-part">
            <div class="logo-part">
                <a class="header-logo" th:href="@{/}">
                    <img alt="" class="img-fluid" src="images/logo.svg">
                    <h5>ape</h5>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-part">
                <div class="nav-logo-bar">
                    <a th:href="@{/}">
                        <img alt="" class="img-fluid" src="images/navbar-logo.svg">
                        <h2>APE</h2>
                    </a>
                    <p>Advertising Promotional Experiences</p>
                </div>
                <nav class="full-nav-bar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a th:href="@{/my-rewards}">My Rewards</a></li>
                        <li><a th:href="@{/about-us}">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a th:href="@{/support}">Support</a></li>
                        <li><a th:href="@{/privacy-policy}">Data Policy</a></li>
                        <li><a th:href="@{/terms-of-use}">Terms of Use</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>

            <div class="toggle-btn">
                <a href="javascript:;">
                    <svg class="fa-bars" viewBox="0 0 448 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M436 124H12c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12V80c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h424c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v32c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12zm0 160H12c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-32c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h424c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v32c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12zm0 160H12c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-32c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h424c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v32c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12z"></path>
                    </svg>
                    <svg class="fa-times" viewBox="0 0 320 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path class=""
                              d="M207.6 256l107.72-107.72c6.23-6.23 6.23-16.34 0-22.58l-25.03-25.03c-6.23-6.23-16.34-6.23-22.58 0L160 208.4 52.28 100.68c-6.23-6.23-16.34-6.23-22.58 0L4.68 125.7c-6.23 6.23-6.23 16.34 0 22.58L112.4 256 4.68 363.72c-6.23 6.23-6.23 16.34 0 22.58l25.03 25.03c6.23 6.23 16.34 6.23 22.58 0L160 303.6l107.72 107.72c6.23 6.23 16.34 6.23 22.58 0l25.03-25.03c6.23-6.23 6.23-16.34 0-22.58L207.6 256z"></path>
                    </svg>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="content-area-container page-ath-wrap">
    <div class="page-ath-content container-fluid" th:object="${contactUsPage}">
        <div class="page-ath-form">
            <div class="page-ath-heading">
                <h3>We’d love to hear from you.</h3>
                <p th:text="*{content}"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="singup-form">
                <form id="form_support" action="javascript:;" th:action="@{/support}" method="post">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="full_name">Full name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="full_name" id="full_name" placeholder="Your name" class="form-control"
                        />

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="you@example.com" class="form-control"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="comment">Comments</label>
                        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="30" rows="8" placeholder="Your comments"
                                  class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn-default bg-blue w-100 mt-5" data-toggle="modal"
                            data-target="#supportmodal">Send
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="supportmodal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog support-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="support-modal-text">
                    <h5>Thank you!</h5>
                    <p>We’ve received your message and we’ll get back to you within 24 hours.</p>
                    <div class="support-modal-btn text-right">
                        <button type="button" class="small-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Okay</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

     $("#form_support").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        });


</script>


<!--js -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/swiper-slider.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you showing all code? I don't see any method, field or class with the `advertisement` name.

Comment: In my project there is no advertisement template so i cannot add advertisement class or field

Comment: But the error message shows something about `advertisement`, so this must be in your code somewhere.